# Understanding Recursive Function Behavior in JavaScript - Unexpected Output

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

Here is the recursion code.

```js
function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        console.log(factorial( (n - 1) ));
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}

const number = 5;
const result = factorial(number);
console.log(result);`
```

```
Output:
1
2
1
6
1
2
1
24
1
2
1
6
1
2
1
120
```

#Why does the output include repeated '1' and '2' values?

#How does the recursive function behave in this scenario, and why does it produce this specific output?

#Is this behavior related to how recursion works in JavaScript?

Comment: Remove `console.log` from the recursive function.

Comment: Because you are doing the recursive call *twice* in your function, so of course it goes down to 1 and 2 to multiple times. If you want to print some intermediate results do `let tmp = factorial(n-1); console.log(tmp); return n * tmp`;

Comment: thanks @derpirscher 

https://www.veed.io/view/eb8e5156-9793-470b-9bf3-b9fab02f21e1?panel=share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `console.log` you are calling `factorial(n-1)` which means you are doing almost the whole calculation twice at each step. Imagine you do `factorial(3)` it will call `factorial(2)` and print it, then it will call `factorial(2)` to be used in the result. Both of the `factorial(2)` calls will do `factorial(1)` twice as well, burt only print it once so you get `1` two times, however each time you increment the argument it will double all the number of printed 1s, 2s, ... n-2, then print the result of `n-1` once before it finally prints the result.

You can cache the result of the recursive call and use it both in printing and in the result. Then you'll only see one of each step:

```js
function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        const rec = factorial(n - 1);
        console.log(rec);
        return n * rec;
    }
}

const number = 5;
const result = factorial(number);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log prints another recursion, instead of printing the current step

```js
function factorial(n) {
    console.log('current value:', n);
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}

const number = 5;
const result = factorial(number);
console.log("result:", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove `console.log` from the recursive function.

**New Code**

```
function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}

const number = 5;
const result = factorial(number);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    console.log("Blastoff!");
  } else {
    console.log(n);
    countdown(n - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.